# For some reason I got Code Analysis errors that are supressed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

For exmaple I got error:

```
CA1056  URI properties should not be strings    Change the type of property 'CoreCallbackServiceConfiguration.UriTemplate' from string to System.Uri.
```

for propery

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1056:UriPropertiesShouldNotBeStrings", Justification = "The template should be string")]
    [DataMember(Name = "uriTemplate")]
    public string UriTemplate { get; set; }
```

you see that there is supress atribute but I still got error. Other people in my team doesn't get this errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you building the same solution configuration (e.g.: Debug vs Release) as the other developers?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu All devs are using debug configuration. Even I  myself sometimes see this errors and sometimes not. Looks like if I made my own CA error in new code - I got alot of such kind fake errors when CA doesn't see supress, and when I remove all my real CA errors(it is hards to find it in this mess) - fake errors also disapears.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
[SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1056:Uri properties should not be strings", Justification = "This is a DB table field")]
```

Keep in mind I'm using this in .NET Core 3. I'm not sure if the analyzers are the same for other versions of .NET.